# How can I post-process files compiled using the Ant javac task?

Tags: ant, javac, post-processing

I need the list of files that were compiled during this run. I want to feed this list to a  subsequent post-processing step.

I have found an [option to list](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) (see listfiles option) the files compiled during this run, but it seems only good for displaying the list on console.

Any idea?

**Edit:** I am talking about incremental compiles, so taking a fileset of the build folder is not an option.

**Edit:** One idea seems to be [custom logger](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=584108) but I am still looking for something simpler

**Edit:** Another idea is to use [depend selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#dependselect) with FileSet before javac and somehow keep the list in memory, to be used after javac has executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can form a fileset about all class-files in the target-directory of the javac.

**Edit:** After the clarification I have to adjust my answer. I didn't such thing yet, but I would try my luck with [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html). The modified-selector looks like the one you want - a fileset of all class-files in a directory, that have changed since the last run. Here is a code-snippet:

```
<fileset dir="${build}">
   <filename name="**/*.class"/>
   <modified/>
</fileset>
```

It does not directly post-process the output of the javac-task, but should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but I am talking about incremental compiles, where JavaC compiles only those .java files that are newer than their compiled .class file

Comment: I adjusted my answer. I hope this helps.